# Google Structured Data testing tool doesn't show questions and answers linked together for a Q/A website with markup

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool, qa

Please take a look at [this](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=en#url=%20https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2432764%2Fchange-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository):

[image]

See? Answers and its question are separated. I mean, they are not link to each other. Also when you open one of the answers, you will see this warning:

[image]

Which clearly says (as far as I understand), answers should be a property of a the question.

---

Ok, I've a Q/A website and implemented schema for it [this way](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=en#url=https%3A%2F%2Flamtakam.com%2Fqanda%2F145%2F%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AC-%DA%AF%D9%88%DA%AF%D9%84-%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%9F)

[image]

See? You don't see any answer item there (noted that question has 5 answers) and all answers are a property of the question. If you click on the "Question" tab you can see the question with along all its answers.

---

Now I want to know, I did it right or I should make it like how SO did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a suitable property exists to link items, the best practice is to use it.

For a Q/A page, you can

- link the `QAPage` item and the `Question` item with the [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property,
- link the `Question` item and all `Answer` items with the [`suggestedAnswer`](https://schema.org/suggestedAnswer) property, and
- if an answer got accepted, link the `Question` item and this `Answer` item with the [`acceptedAnswer`](https://schema.org/acceptedAnswer) property.

There is only one reason not do this: If you know that a structured data consumer (which you want to support) can’t work with this structure. I’m not aware of any, and it would certainly be a badly implemented consumer (standing in the way of valid structured data following best practices), but who knows what’s out there.

So in your case (unless you know of such a consumer), I would simply add `itemprop="mainEntity"` to the element for the `Question`, thereby connecting the `QAPage`, the `Question`, and all `Answer` items.

Comment: Thank you .. [I've linked all items to each other, is it correct now?](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=en#url=https%3A%2F%2Flamtakam.com%2Fqanda%2F145%2F%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AC-%DA%AF%D9%88%DA%AF%D9%84-%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%9F) .. also still I'm wonder why SO doesn't do that.

Comment: @MartinAJ: Yes, with respect to connecting these three types, your structured data is correct.

Comment: @unor Any idea how can I link [these two items](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=en#url=https%3A%2F%2Flamtakam.com%2Fabout) to each other? (AboutPage and Person)

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Please don’t ask questions on comments that aren’t closely related to the Q/A post’s topic. -- Instead, post a new question and provide all necessary details: what is the relation between the two items, did you find properties that you wonder about or ruled out etc.